# Do degrees determine the chromatic number?

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose $G, H$ are finite, simple, undirected graphs and there is a bijection between the vertex sets $\varphi:V(G) \to V(H)$ such that for all $v\in V$ we have $$\text{deg}_G(v) = \deg_H(\varphi(v)).$$

Does this imply that $\chi(G) = \chi(H)$?

Comment: In other words, $G,H$ have the same degree sequence.

Comment: Play with the Petersen graph. Its edges have no three coloring. Now `untwist' it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $G$ be a 6-cycle and let $H$ be two 3-cycles.

Or, if you want them connected, let $G$ be a 6-cycle with an extra edge between vertices 1 and 3, and $H$ a 6-cycle with an extra edge between vertices 1 and 4.

Comment: One can even make this example connected - add a "diameter" edge to $G$ and an edge connecting two triangles to $H$.

Comment: Isn't simpler argument all $k$-regular graphs would have the same chromatic number?

Comment: Well, all $k$-regular graphs of a given order.

Comment: @joro: I figured that if the OP knew that not all $k$-regular graphs of a given order had the same chromatic number, he wouldn't have asked the question.  So I didn't think just quoting the fact would be helpful, and thus I gave an explicit example instead.  (Incidentally, my first example consists of two 2-regular graphs of order 6.)

Answer (score 1):

There is also a general principle one can apply: If you have any parameter $\alpha$ of  graphs so that there is an efficient (polynomial-time) algorithm to compute $\alpha (G)$, then it is extremely implausible that $\alpha$ determines the chromatic number since this would imply that $P=NP$. (It is known that computing the chromatic number is $NP$-hard.)

Comment: Could't it still be that it is NP complete to determine whether a degree sequence is, say, "three colorable"?